# Displaying validation error instead of default text errors in Django UserCreationForm

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a very simple registration form on my website. My form works, but if a username already exists or my 2 password fields don't match, after I submit the form, Django does not do anything and just focuses the field with the error.

**Forms.py**

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
  username = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=30) 
  email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
  first_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
  last_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
  
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2',]
```

If anyone needs any more details, feel free to let me know. Thank you to everyone who helps!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out. Basically, you need to make a function inside of your **forms.py** file and query the default Django SQL database in order to see if the username already exists. For anyone having the same problem as me, my code is down below.

---

```
def clean(self):
          cleaned_data=super().clean()
          if User.objects.filter(username=cleaned_data["username"]).exists():
            raise ValidationError("The username is taken, please try another one")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you can show errors from the form in your template. Something like this:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            {{ error|escape }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        {{ error|escape }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Detailed documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors

Comment: Thank you! Let me try that.

Comment: Thank you for helping, but your answer does not display the error as a validation error, it outputs text. This is what I want it to look like: https://docs.google.com/document/d/10SKc0cpJRLNJ5g9XmWmdzuFLytt99BJ3oP9TmFjHEpU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @boetis that validation you show in that document is not done by Django it is done by _your browser itself_. If you want to do things like that you will need to use JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not really that good with Javascript. Do you have an example you can show me?

Comment: Do you want to get errors before sending form? It can be implemented with js.

Comment: I'm not sure, but form widgets could be useful for you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at that.

Comment: Your link didn't really help me. It talks about widgets. I want to display a validation error if the username already exists. Django displays the error if I submit the field and leave it blank, how can I get the error message if a username already exists?