# How to see if username already exists in UserCreationField - Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am creating a simple registration field in Django for my website. I want to see if a username already exists and display an error if it does. For example, if I had an account with the username of **hi**, and another user tried to create an account with the username of **hi**, after they click on the submit button, I want to raise an error. Right now, if I was to create an account with a username that already exists, Django will not create the account but does not display an error. My code is down bellow.

**Views.py**

```
def index(request,*args, **kwargs):
  return render(request, "index.html", {} )

def register(request, ):
  form = CreateUserForm()
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
      messages.success(request, f'Your account has been successfully created, {username} ')
      return redirect('login')


    

  context = {'form': form}
  return render(request, "register.html",  context )


def login(request,):
  return render(request,"login.html")
```

**Forms.py**

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
  username = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=30, ) 
  email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
  first_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
  last_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2',]
```

**I don't know if you need this but here is my register.html:**

```
<!--Might need to inherit from base.html-->
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "registerstyles.css" %}">
<title>GoodDeed - Register</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="signup-form" style=" position:absolute; top: -1.5%; left: 38%;">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <h2 style=>Sign Up</h2>
        <p style="font-size: xx-small; color: #f2f2f2;">---</p>
        
        {% csrf_token %} 
        {{form|crispy}}
        
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
            <a href="/login" style="position: absolute; top: 90%; left: 50%; font-size: 16px !important;">Already a user? Sign in!</a>


            
        

        </div>
    </form>

    <!--Sidebar bellow-->
    
</body>

</html>
```

### Thank you to everyone who helps!

******EDIT***

NEW FORMS.PY CODE***

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
  username = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=30, ) 
  email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
  first_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
  last_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)

  
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2',]



  def clean(self):
    cleaned_data=super.clean()
    if User.objects.filter(username=cleaned_data["username"].exists():
      raise ValidationError("The username is taken, please try another one")
```

Comment: Do you have a custom user model? If this is the default user model from auth the model form should be validating the uniqueness of the user. And `{{form|crispy}}` _should_ be rendering the error for it.

Comment: Crispy forms is rendering an error, but a non formatted text error. I want to raise an error if the username already exists.

Comment: Ah, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67850935/displaying-validation-error-instead-of-default-text-errors-in-django-usercreatio/67851170#comment119928904_67851170 why do you people do this? Ask one question **one time** only please. To repeat what I said to that previous user the type of validation popup you expect is not done by Django that is default validation done by _browsers_, if you want popups like that you would need to use _JavaScript_ (some CSS, too) and hence would be better off researching in that direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying validation error instead of default text errors in Django UserCreationForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67850935/displaying-validation-error-instead-of-default-text-errors-in-django-usercreatio)

Comment: No, that question does not have a definite answer and does not work in my case

Comment: Well I mark it as a duplicate because it is the _same question_ and you have the _exact_ same code. This obviously is not a _coincidence_ (Please **don't** do such things) and having two questions asking the same thing is obviously counterintuitive.

Answer (score 2):

In your form implement the `clean` function as shown [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
     .....
     def clean(self):
          cleaned_data=super().clean()
          if User.objects.filter(username=cleaned_data["username"].exists():
               raise ValidationError("The username is taken, please try another one")
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by implementing a clean function. Can you please show me the clean function in my program?

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work. I am getting a syntax error at the end of my 24th line of code in forms.py. I am going to update my question with my new code, this seems like a very easy fix.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code.

Comment: can you please take a look?

Comment: super().clean()

Comment: Thank you, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Which line is 24?

Comment: There is a missing bracket. if User.objects.filter(username=cleaned_data["username"]).exists():

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233360/discussion-between-mkalioby-and-xxxbabyslayerxxx).